# Is it possible to underclock or set a frequency to Intel HD 4000 (IGP)

Tags: intel-graphics, overclocking

I have a Samsung NP530 ultrabook and it run very hot and loud when the IGP is in use (eg. on Google maps with 3D building, etc...).

I don't need a lot of power and I prefer when I work in silence so I already activate Powersave governor for the CPU and limit its frequency to 800Mhz. Even with a high CPU load it keep cool but I didn't find anything to keep cool the GPU (HD 4000).

So is it possible to underclock or set a frequency to Intel HD 2/3/4000 (IGP) to keep it cool ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not having seen this before but I wrote an article on how to play with GPU frequencies on that laptop [Playing with the GPU frequencies on a Samsung NP530-U3C](http://blog.terranux.net/2013/11/playing-with-the-gpu-frequencies-on-a-samsung-np530-u3c/)

short extract:

```
sudo su
echo 350 > /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_max_freq
```

will reduce the max GPU speed to 350Mhz, the lowest speed

Comment: cool very cool :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by user fmo does not actually work. The correct way of limiting is described [in this Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404049/how-to-stop-intel-hd4000-from-running-at-max-clock-speed)

Here is the short version:

`echo 350 | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_boost_freq_mhz` to set the boost clock to 350MHz.

`echo 350 | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz` to set the max clock to 350MHz.

Supported clock speeds may vary between models.

To see the clock speed change in action, use `intel-gpu-overlay` (part of package `intel-gpu-tools`).

Note: if the max clock is set to 650 and boost clock to 1250 then under heavy load the boost clock will be used.

Think of it like Intel Turbo Boost for CPU-s, max clock is the base clock speed and boost clock is the turbo boost clock speed.