# Ubuntu 14.04.3 Intel HD 4000 stuck at 1050-1100Mhz => Heat

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, nvidia-optimus, intel-hd

Samsung NP550P5C S02 i5-3210M, Intel HD 4000, Nvidia GT 650M Ubuntu 14.04.3, kernel 3.19, xorg 1.17 nvidia-352 Ubuntu 14.04.3 Mesa 10.5.9

```
dmesg
```

gives me some

```
[ 4565.419502] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
[ 4592.479139] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection
```

while gaming with primusrun after a few minutes, so the games lag A LOT!

So I realised it is my intel card on high frequency all the time (1100Mhz)

Any suggestions how to reduce its clock??!! Should i post any more logs?!!

What i've already tried and didnt help:

```
1.TLP 

2.laptop-mode-tools

3.disabling turbo boost
(echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo)

4.updating intel_microcode (update successful, but no change)

5.putting i915.enable_rc6=1 on GRUB boot parameters (no change whatsoever,
  maybe it is enabled by default for my card)
```

[Is it possible to underclock or set a frequency to Intel HD 4000 (IGP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505010/is-it-possible-to-underclock-or-set-a-frequency-to-intel-hd-4000-igp)

The above question is similar, but i would like a cleaner and less risky solution to make my card manage itself properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of a problem on a Samsung notebook too.
After looking into the logs I found that a CPU microcode update was needed.

You can do it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

Samsung does not release bioses with new microcode. That is a problem.

It may solve your problem. I had the same generation Core i3.

You can also try to toggle CPU powersafe in BIOS, if the first solution does not help.

Comment: isn't updating intel microcode risky?! i mean... i may be dumb, but could it potentially be dangerous?!!!Also the slowdown didn't happen with nvidia-prime nvidia-331, but prime doesnt work for me with any driver after 340, so i switched to bumblebee and here i am!!

Comment: Updating microcode is not risky at all. It is loaded only until reboot. It is not persistent.

Comment: does it work with UEFI? Did your samsung laptop have Windows 8 preinstalled?!! If so i will definitely try it today!

Comment: Why? It does work with any bios/UEFI. I have an UEFI laptop. It was designed for Win8, but I bought it without OS.

Comment: Successfully updated the microcode, but i still get 1100Mhz

Comment: and CPU powersaving is definitely enabled, since i didn;t get  any such problems on Windows/nvidia-prime!